# Send task to specific celery worker

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, celerybeat

I'm building a web application (Using Python/Django) that is hosted on two machines connected to a load balancer.

I have a central storage server, and I have a central Redis server, single celery beat, and two celery workers on each hosting machine.

I receive files from an API endpoint (on any of the hosting machines) and then schedule a task to copy to the storage server.

The problem is that the task is scheduled using:

```py
task.delay(args)
```

and then any worker can receive it, while the received files exist only on one of the 2 machines, and have to be copied from it.

I tried finding if there's a unique id for the worker that I can assign the task to but didn't find any help in the docs.

Any solution to this ? Given that the number of hosting machines can scale to more than 2.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to put the task onto a named queue and have each worker look for jobs from their specific queue. So if you have Machine A and Machine B you could have Queue A, Queue B and Queue Shared. Machine A would watch for jobs on Queue A and Queue Shared while Machine B looked for jobs on Queue B and Queue Shared.

Comment: Yep, that is what I have used in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to have a **dedicated queue** for each worker.

When I was learning Celery I did exactly this, and after few years completely abandoned this approach as it creates more problems than it actually solves.

Instead, I would recommend the following: any resource that you may need to share among tasks should be on a shared filesystem (NFS), or in some sort of in-memory caching servise like Redis, KeyDb or memcached. We use a combination of S3 and Redis, depending on the type of resource.

Sure, if you do not really care about scalability the queue-per-worker approach will work fine.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, can you please elaborate "it creates more problems than it actually solves", what type of problems occurred ?